# Can't read directory propertly

Tags: go

I'm trying to unzip a directory, check whether the subdirectories are alphabetical `char`, and traverse the files within the giver subdirectories.
The problem is that I'm getting an error that says the `ENOTDIR (3)`
I tried several options for `dirFiles, err := os.ReadDir("./"+file.Name)`,
with `./` or `/` but I'm missing something over here.

```
dir
│   
└───A
│     file011.pfx
│     file012.cert
└───B
     file021.txt
     file022.txt
```

```
func openZipFile(sc ServerConfig, path string) ([]byte, error) {
    var split []string
    // Create a zipReader out of the zip archive
    zipReader, err := zip.OpenReader(path)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer zipReader.Close()
    // Iterate through each file/dir found in
    for _, file := range zipReader.Reader.File {
        // Open the file inside the zip archive
        // like a normal file
        zippedFile, err := file.Open()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer zippedFile.Close()

        if file.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            mapTest := make(map[string]ZipStructure)
            // preserves permissions
            log.Println("Creating directory:", file.Name)
            split = strings.Split(file.Name, "/")
            lastFileName := split[len(split) - 2]
            match, err := regexp.MatchString("^[A-Za-z]+$", lastFileName)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            if match {
                dirFiles, err := os.ReadDir("./"+file.Name)
                if err != nil{
                    return nil,err
                }
                for _, dirFile := range dirFiles {
                    if !dirFile.IsDir() {
                        file, err := os.Open(dirFile.Name())
                        if err != nil {
                            return nil, err
                        }
                        defer file.Close()

                        bytes, err := io.ReadAll(file)
                        if err != nil {
                            return nil, err
                        }

                        split := strings.Split(file.Name(), ".")
                        sc.ClusterSetupZip[split[0]] = ZipStructure{}
                        switch split[0] {
                        case "pfx":
                            mapTest[split[0]] = ZipStructure{Pfx: bytes}
                        case "cert":
                            mapTest[split[0]] = ZipStructure{Cert: bytes}
                        }
                    }
                }



                //_, err := ReadFileAndReturnByteArray(sc,lastFileName)
                //if err != nil {
                //  return nil, err
                //}


            }
            //err := os.MkdirAll(extractedFilePath, file.Mode())
            //if err != nil {
            //  return nil, err
            //}
        }
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `file` is of type `*zip.File`, which represent a file inside the zip archive, not a valid file on disk, so you should not use `os.ReadDir` on `file.Name`.

Refer to
https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip?utm_source=gopls#example-Reader.